# How to delete an item with a button in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, swift5

I program in swift5 and want to delete the a content in realm, which i append to the array before. But i dont know how to implemented it into the code.

Here is the code snippets for appending an item to the list, but now I need a second button called deleteButtonPressed to delete the item.

```
 @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var textField = UITextField()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add new todoey item", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { (action) in
        //what will happen once the user clicks the Add Item button on our UIAlert
        //print("Success") //print ot the debug console
        //print("Add item present")
        //print(textField.text)

        if let currentCategory = self.selectedCategory {
            do {
                try self.realm.write {

                           let newItem = Item()
                           newItem.title = textField.text!
                           currentCategory.items.append(newItem)

                       }

                    } catch {
                        print("Error saving new items, \(error)")
                    }
                }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new item"
        textField = alertTextField

    }


    alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Comment: did you try `realm.delete()`?

Comment: This is covered in the Realm Getting Started Guide [Deleting Objects](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#deleting-objects). It's always a good ideas to consult the documentation before posting a question as what you trying to do may be covered.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. All you have to do is use the `delete` method on realm.

Example:

```
try? self.realm.write {
    self.realm.delete(/* The Object you wanna delete */)
}
```

If your aim is to delete the last added object, the following code should do:

```
try? self.realm.write {
    if let item = currentCategory.items.last {
        self.realm.delete(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks nicholas,  thats what I look for

Comment: how to delete the selected row instead of last row of the last item? Thanks